# SQL Server report by comparing consecutive rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+--------------+------------+--------+
|     Acno     | ValueDate  | Amount |
+--------------+------------+--------+
| 190010283045 | 20/01/2015 |  -3000 |
| 190010283045 | 20/01/2015 |   3000 |
| 190010283045 | 20/01/2015 |  -3000 |
| 190010283118 | 08/01/2015 |    100 |
| 190010283118 | 08/01/2015 |    100 |
| 190010283266 | 19/01/2015 |  -3500 |
| 190010283266 | 19/01/2015 |   3500 |
| 190010283533 | 14/01/2015 |  -5000 |
| 190010283533 | 16/01/2015 |   5000 |
+--------------+------------+--------+
```

The requirement is to compare two consecutive rows in the table:

1. If Acno is the same,
2. Then If the ValueDate is the same
3. Then if the sum of the Amount in the two rows is = 0
4. Then both the rows should be flagged as 1

A row once flagged should not be used for comparison again.

Hence, the desired report for the above table would be:

```
+--------------+------------+--------+------+
|     Acno     | ValueDate  | Amount | Flag |
+--------------+------------+--------+------+
| 190010283045 | 20/01/2015 |  -3000 |    1 |
| 190010283045 | 20/01/2015 |   3000 |    1 |
| 190010283045 | 20/01/2015 |  -3000 |      |
| 190010283118 | 08/01/2015 |    100 |      |
| 190010283118 | 08/01/2015 |    100 |      |
| 190010283266 | 19/01/2015 |  -3500 |    1 |
| 190010283266 | 19/01/2015 |   3500 |    1 |
| 190010283533 | 14/01/2015 |  -5000 |      |
| 190010283533 | 16/01/2015 |   5000 |      |
| 190010283533 | 27/01/2015 |  -5000 |      |
+--------------+------------+--------+------+
```

Comment: In your first three rows you have nothing to indicate the order of the rows. You need an actual data column to unambiguously define the order of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TALBE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Acno   BIGINT  , ValueDate DATE , Amount NUMERIC(20,2))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 190010283045 , '01/20/2015' ,  -3000 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283045 , '01/20/2015' ,   3000 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283045 , '01/20/2015' ,  -3000 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283118 , '01/08/2015' ,    100 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283118 , '01/08/2015' ,    100
UNION ALL 
SELECT 190010283266 , '01/19/2015' ,  -3500 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283266 , '01/19/2015' ,   3500 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283533 , '01/14/2015' ,  -5000 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283533 , '01/16/2015' ,   5000 
UNION ALL
SELECT 190010283533 , '01/27/2015' ,   -5000
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACNO,ValueDate 
    ORDER BY ACNO,(SELECT 0))RNO, *
    FROM #TEMP
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT C1.*,C2.RNO RNO1,C2.ACNO ACNO1, C2.ValueDate VD,C2.Amount AM,
    CASE WHEN C1.ValueDate=C2.ValueDate AND (C1.Amount+C2.Amount)=0 THEN 1 
    ELSE NULL END COL
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON 
    (C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1 AND C1.ValueDate=C2.ValueDate) --AND ((C2.RNO-1)%2=0 OR C1.RNO=1))
    WHERE C1.RNO%2 <> 0
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    SELECT RNO,ACNO,ValueDate,Amount,COL FLAG
    FROM CTE2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RNO1,ACNO1,VD,AM,COL
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE RNO1 IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT ACNO,ValueDate,Amount,FLAG
 FROM CTE3
ORDER BY ACNO,RNO
```

Feel free to ask for any changes.